# Which Arduino is compatible for atmega164pa

Tags: avr

I am working on a project using 5 pins of ADC, 5 pins for PWM, and LCD. I need to use Atmega164pa. I would like to know how I can transfer it to Arduino. Is there any Arduino compatible with this chip?

Comment: You could port it yourself. It's not that hard.

Comment: @MattYoung what do you mean? do you suggest to avoid using Arduino?

Comment: Well actually yes, but you could port the Arduino libraries to a new device easily.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to use the 164PA?

Comment: @microtherion the reason is that ATMEGA16 does support at most 4 PWM channels while I need 5 PWM channels.

Comment: My question was meant to be more along the lines of why it would be an 164PA rather than a 644PA or 1284PA; for the latter, there used to be the Sanguino board, though it's not clear whether these still are produced.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Arduino core for the ['1284A](https://github.com/maniacbug/mighty-1284p), but it can be adapted to the '164A.

Comment: but the link is to the software not to the board. What is the name of board that I can buy for this software.

Comment: You don't need a board for it; the DIL package mounts on a breadboard.

Comment: sorry but what is DIL package?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package